# Disappearing text in generated PDF with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a problem with generating PDFs using TCPDF. To generate pdf I use writeHTML function.

Problem is that some text in my PDF displays randomly. Or maybe some parts of it disappears.
Here is how my PDF look like:
[image]

Under the table should be visible more text. My HTML for this PDF:

```
<br/><br/>
<table cellpadding="5" width="670">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="100">Data</td>
        <td width="100">Typ</td>
        <td width="370">Opis - Items</td>
        <td width="100">Kwota - Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <?php if(!empty($this->finances)) : ?>
    <?php foreach($this->finances as $finance) :?>
    <?php if($finance['value'] != 0) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="100"><?= $finance['date']->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); ?></td>
        <td width="100"><?= ($finance['type'] == 'invoice') ? 'Fv nr '. $finance['invoice_no'] : 'Płatność - Paid'; ?></td>
        <td width="370"><?= $finance['description']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: right;" width="100"><?= $finance['value_sign'].$finance['value']; ?> PLN</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;" width="570">Saldo:</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;" width="100"><?= sprintf('%s%.2f', $this->balance['sign'], $this->balance['balance']); ?> PLN</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div style="font-size: 20pt;">Information – Informacje</div>
<p>(*) The sign “ – “ is put behind an amount invoiced by the School ; the sign “ +” is put behind an amount received by the School or a reduction calculated in accordance with School rules. When appearing, the line “bilans otwarcia” indicates the balance at the end of previous preschool year on 30.06.2017. Please kindly be informed that starting 15th October 2017, the School is obliged to apply legal interest penalty on delayed payment.</p>
<p>(**) Znak “ – “ pojawi się przed kwotami fakturowanymi przez Szkołę ; znak „ + „ pojawi się przed wpłatami otrzymanymi od państwa lub przed zniżkami kalkulowanymi zgodnie z regułami Szkoły. Kiedy jest pokazana pozycja „bilans otwarcia” oznacza to saldo na koniec zeszlego roku szkolnego tj. 30.06.2017. Uprzejmie informujemy że od 15-ego Pażdziernika 2017, Szkoła jest zobowiązana do stosowania ustawowych odsetek za opóżnione płatności. </p>
<p>(***) Le signe „ – „ apparait devant les montants facturés par l’Ecole ; le signe « + » apparaît devant les montants reçus par l’Ecole ou devant une reduction calculée selon le règlement de l’Ecole Quand elle apparait, la ligne « bilans otwarcia » indique le solde à la fin de l’année scolaire précédente, au 30.06.2017. Depuis le 15 Octobre 2017, la Maternelle est amenée à appliquer les intérêts de retard légaux sur le paiement des frais de scolarité.</p>
```

And here is the code for generating PDF:

```
$this->SetFont('times', '', 11, true);
$this->setPrintHeader(false);
$this->SetMargins(10, 10, 10);
$this->AddPage('P');

$this->view->balance = array('paid' => $paid, 'to_pay' => $to_pay, 'balance' => $balance, 'sign' => ($balance <= 0) ? '' : '+');
$this->view->finances = $finances;
$this->view->child = $child;
if(!empty($child['GroupChild']) && !empty($child['GroupChild'][0]['group_id'])) {
     $group = Doctrine::getTable('Group')->findOneBy('group_id', $child['GroupChild'][0]['group_id']);
     if($group && strtolower($group->name) != 'outgoing'){
         $this->view->group = $group->name;
     } else $this->view->group = '';
} else $this->view->group = '';

$this->view->iban = $iban;
$this->view->now = new Zend_Date();

$html = $this->render('balance', 'html');

$this->writeHTML($html);
```

Is there any fast way to repair this without generating PDF manually? I use Zend Framework 1.12 and class which generates PDF inherits from TCPDF.

Some time ago I have similar problem but it was unsolved to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677662/text-disappeared-in-table-in-generated-pfd-by-tcpdf

Comment: `line-height: 1pt;` ?

Comment: I added it to test it change something. Without it text is not displayed too.

Comment: I noticed that the text disappears if there is a space before the closing tag, e.g. </p>. Have you already solved this problem? Will you write how?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of special characters under your table.

Did you try to :

- change the charset ('ISO-8859-1' or other character map) in your tcpdf instantiation ?
- encode $html before sending it to tcpdf : `$html = utf8_encode($html);`